# How do I connect points inside a graph so that their paths don't cross?

Tags: python, graph, path, graph-theory, path-finding

I'm working on an algorithmic problem. As input I get graphs defined. Each has a height, width and some points that have a name.

My task is to determine if all the points can be connected to another point with the same name. Their paths can't cross.

Could you help me with my algorithm? I can't figure out why even the inputs that should return "possible" keep returning "impossible"

```py
# Function to read input from a file and process it
def is_possible_to_connect(h, w, named_vertices):
    # Create a grid to represent the graph.
    graph = [[None for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)]

    # Initialize the graph with named vertices
    for (row, col, name) in named_vertices:
        if 0 <= row < h and 0 <= col < w:
            if graph[row][col] is None:
                graph[row][col] = name
            else:
                return "impossible"  # Two named vertices with the same coordinates
        else:
            return "impossible"  # Named vertex coordinates out of bounds

    # Define the four possible directions (up, down, left, right)
    directions = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

    def is_valid_move(row, col):
        return 0 <= row < h and 0 <= col < w

    def dfs(row, col, prev_name):
        if not is_valid_move(row, col):
            return True  # Reached outside the grid

        # Check if we encounter a named vertex or a path
        current_vertex = graph[row][col]
        if current_vertex is not None:
            if current_vertex != prev_name:
                return False  # Encountered a different named vertex
            else:
                return True  # Reached the same named vertex again

        graph[row][col] = prev_name  # Mark the current cell as visited

        # Recursively explore all four directions
        for dr, dc in directions:
            if not dfs(row + dr, col + dc, prev_name):
                return False

        return True

    # Check if it's possible to connect the named vertices without crossing
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            if graph[row][col] is not None:
                if not dfs(row, col, graph[row][col]):
                    return "impossible"

    return "possible"


data = [
    (2, 3, [(0, 1, 'A'), (0, 2, 'B'), (2, 1, 'C'), (2, 0, 'D')]), #impossible
    (2, 3, [(1, 0, 'A'), (2, 1, 'A')]), #possible
    (2, 3, [(1, 3, 'A'), (0, 0, 'B'), (0, 1, 'A'), (2, 0, 'B')]), #possible
    (2, 3, [(2, 3, 'A'), (1, 0, 'A'), (0, 1, 'B'), (2, 2, 'B')]) #impossible
]

for row in data:
    h, w, name = row
    result = is_possible_to_connect(h, w, named_vertices)
    print(result)
```

Expected output:
impossible
possible
possible
impossible

Actual output:
impossible
impossible
impossible
impossible

Only similar problem I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183668/how-to-connect-two-points-without-crossing-another-path), but it leads to a crazy technical pdf theoretical analysis. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the problem more. What if the segments *touch* in one point? e.g `(0, 0, 'A'), (1, 1, 'A'), (1, 1, 'B'), (2, 2, 'B')`. But, if I understand you correctly, do you search only for segment intersections?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, the paths can't cross, meaning only path intersection. But in the task there's also defined, that no point lies on the same coordinates, so it doesn't matter

Comment: Just to be clear, how big is your input?

Comment: @AndrejKesely it depends, can be over 500 inputs, the inputs provided are test data

Comment: I see you've defined the 4 possible directions. So by that logic `(0, 1, 'A')` and `(1, 3, 'A')` shouldn't connect?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm not actually sure... The task I have is losely defined, IDK if you can move diagonally.. maybe if yes, there might be the bug

Answer (score 1):

```
Check if it's possible to connect the named vertices without crossing
for row in range(h):
    for col in range(w):
        if graph[row][col] is not None:
            if not dfs(row, col, graph[row][col]):
```

This code search for paths between identical named vertices as the are enountered.  It uses DFS to find these paths, so for the first pair it finds the most direct route.  This route may block another pair from reaching each other, that could have reached each other if the first pair used a more indirect route.

For example

[image]

While there is no obvious way to prevent this happening in every case, there are some obvious way to improve your algorithm:

1. Since shorter connections are less likely to block other pairs, you should sort the pairs into ascending order of distance apart, and put down the path between the closer pairs first.
2. Vertex pairs on the  grid boundaries are most likely to block other pairs, do these last.

... and so on with diminishing returns

Answer (score 0):

It's returning impossible because the test data points are off the grid. So it exits at: 
`# Named vertex coordinates out of bounds`

You either want to change the if statement to

```py
if 0 < row <= h and 0 < col <= w:
   ...
```

or decrease the coordinates of the points in your named vertices list.

Comment: You're right about the code exiting on the line (I labeled the exit points for clarity, good idea). But the solution doesn't work, as the indeces are out of bouds when you change them..

Comment: Well you need to make sure the coordinates are on the grid no? It seems like you want to use a zero-indexed grid, so just make sure you don't put in any coordinates where the coordinate is equal to `h` or `w`, since it's zero indexed those won't be on the grid. In that case you can leave the if statement unchanged.